# JavaScript regular expression for java.sql.Date

Tags: javascript

In my app all the dates are saved using java.util.Date format:

```
YYYY-mm-DD (year, month, day)
```

So 1988-05-13 is a valid date.
So I think only digits are valid, month is [1:12], day is [1:30] 
E.g. this is a regular expression I use for my logins

```
/^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i
```

Which JavaScript regular expression should I use to check this date?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression for date format- dd-mm-yyyy in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937408/regular-expression-for-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript) (Just change the order)

Comment: Be sure the regular expression can say positive response for wrong date like 55551-99-23. So use try to use some pre-defined library to validate date. I feel "datejs" is more powerful handling this stuff.

Comment: Ever thought about just using `split("-")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let [`Date.parse()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.6) do the hard work for you:

```
function isValidDate(str){
    return !isNaN(Date.parse(str));
}
```

`Date.parse(str)` will return `NaN` if  `str` isn't a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
/^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$/
```

will check for the correct format - but it won't check for the valid range of the month and day. I don't think there is a way to do that with regular expressions.