# Reg Exp for Javascript pattern MM / YYYY

Tags: javascript, regex

Does anyone have a reference for to a javascript reg exp for the date pattern MM / YYYY?
I've been researching only to find the usual MM/DD/YYYY, etc.

Comment: And what is the problem? Just take the part matching "/DD" out.

Comment: Reference to JavaScript regex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about:

This literal here for a regex:     `/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}/`

alternatively it looks like you're wanting space between the m and ys so:

`/[\d]{2} \/ [\d]{4}/`

Comment: Depending on the use, you might want to anchor it with `^` and `$`

Comment: You don't need `[]` if you're only matching `\d`. The question actually has spaces around the `/`.

Comment: It would be as MM/YYYY, without the spaces

Comment: Indeed I should have added the ^ to the beginning to ensure an exact match `/^[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}/`

Comment: @Ben Be careful with this solution.  It allows months 13-99.  Check out dav's solution so your month is 1-12.

Comment: I'm using this with DOJO and had to mash some stuff so the final was ^([0-2][0-9]\/(19|20)[0-9]{2})$... dojo for some reason doesn't like [/d]

Answer (score 5):

`(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(\d{4})`

This ensures you get a valid month, whether it be two or one digits. I'm assuming you don't want to restrict the year.

http://rubular.com/r/W461W8GyHn

Answer (score 1):

My answer is:

> (0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(\d{4}[^0-9])

Example: http://regexr.com?35cl5

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the part of the regex that matches the day (DD). In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937408/regular-expression-for-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript) similar post, the answer

```
function parseDate(str) {
  var m = str.match(/^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})$/);
  return (m) ? new Date(m[3], m[2]-1, m[1]) : null;
}
```

was given. Just edit the regex slightly to remove one of the 2 decimal matches, and you get the function

```
  var m = str.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex for this

```
var date=input.split("/");
var month=parseInt(date[0],10);
var year=parseInt(date[1],10);

if(isNaN(month) || isNaN(year))//invalid string
else //check if month and year is valid
```

`parseInt` would evaluate to `NaN` incase the format is not proper.So,in a way you are validating the string

---

If you want regex

```
 ^\d{2}/\d{4}$
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question though...

Comment: @Bluetoft it would throw `NaN` in case string is not well formed

Comment: true... but you still didn't provide a regex as the op requested.

Comment: @Anirudh The question was in the form of 'How can I do this with regex?' and you answered in the form of 'Here's a solution that doesn't use regex'.  It's not an argument of whether your solution finds a valid month and year, it's an argument of not satisfying the requirements of the question.

Comment: @RyanWH still he would have to individually check if month and year is valid by parsing it to int..there is no need of regex

Comment: @Anirudh You can't be sure of that, as you don't know his entire problem.  If he was wanting a regex to simply detect if there's a month and a year, he could use dav's solution.  dav's solution allows a leading zero on the month and only allows 1-12.  No parsing is required.