# Regex date pattern yyyy-mm-dd javascript in java script?

Tags: javascript

Regex date pattern yyyy-mm-dd **javascript** in java script, to compare from and to dates in the form, need to check To date is beyond the from date and dates should not the same ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do you need a pattern to check if the string needed is a date?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937408/regular-expression-for-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript

Comment: Need the Regular expression to check the date formate in YYYY/MM/DD

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any regular-expressions, you can use `Date.parse` to read-in ISO-8061 formatted dates and compare them directly:

```
var date1 = Date.parse("2015-12-14");
var date2 = Date.parse("2015-12-15");
return date1 < date2; // true
```

Note that `Date.parse` actually returns an `integer` value. It returns `NaN` if the string could not be parsed as a date.

Use the `Date(string)` constructor to get an actual `Date` instance:

```
var date1 = new Date("2015-12-14");
var date2 = new Date("2015-12-15");
return date1 < date2; // true
```

...however the `Date(string)` constructor will throw an exception on invalid input, so if you need to test a date first, do this:

```
var isValidDate = !isNaN( Date.parse( dateString ) );
if( isValidDate ) return new Date( dateString );
```

Or if you're feeling very efficient and want to avoid parsing the string twice:

```
var timestamp = Date.parse( dateString );
if( !isNaN( timestamp ) ) return new Date( timestamp );
```

Comment: Can you be more specific i need to compare the dates kess, greater, same dates in YYYY/MM/DD formate can U have any

Comment: @GaneshSudarsan You should be able to pass the string values directly to the `Date(string)` constructor and compare the instances. What problem are you having specifically?

Comment: Hi, on validating form I am giving inputs as from (2015/02/__) & To date (2015/02/__) in those input dates Iam giving Year, Month but not Date even though it is acception and submiting the form

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expression. In fact, you don't even need to parse the date as suggested by @Dai. Dates in the ISO-8601 format can be compared as strings:

```
'2015-12-14' < '2015-12-15' // true
'2015-12-20' == '2015-12-20' // true
```

Alphabetical sorting of the strings will yield dates chronologically, because of the ordering, i.e. year first, then month, then day, and because of the leading `0` in single digit numbers, such that `04 < 10`.

This, of course, implies that the strings are always valid ISO-8601 dates.

Comment: This is why the American `MM/dd/yyyy` system makes no sense :D