# How to convert timestamp to custom format in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a string (data with hours and seconds = "2020-02-02T11:00:00Z") and I am trying to convert it to custom format (20200201_110000).

Can someone is there any built in function in python (like calendar in Java) which will help me with this ?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python datetime tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score -2):

Use regular expression to convert as you want

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=regex

[Regular expression for date format- dd-mm-yyyy in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937408/regular-expression-for-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-in-javascript)