# Validating Date with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need a regex to pattern match the following -

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

The following date entries should pass validation:

- 05/03/2012
- 5/03/2012
- 05/3/2012
- 5/3/2012

Also, after validating above `regex`, what is the best way convert above date `string` to `Date` object?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html simply adjust the order of the date components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the check and the parsing in one go, using split, parseInt and [the Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) :

```
function toDate(s) {
  var t = s.split('/');
  try {
     if (t.length!=3) return null;
     var d = parseInt(t[1],10);
     var m = parseInt(t[0],10);
     var y = parseInt(t[2],10);
     if (d>0 && d<32 && m>0 && m<13) return new Date(y, m-1, d);
  } catch (e){}
}

var date = toDate(somestring);
if (date) // ok
else // not ok
```

[DEMONSTRATION :](http://jsfiddle.net/wjCgL/)

```
01/22/2012 ==> Sun Jan 22 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
07/5/1972 ==> Wed Jul 05 1972 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CEST)
999/99/1972 ==> invalid
```

As other answers of this page, this wouldn't choke for 31 in February. That's why for all serious purposes you should instead use a library like [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

Comment: Interesting solution but it will happily accept 99/99/99 as a valid date. The JavaScript Date function will produce a valid date form any  any numeric values. You should validate them before calling date.

Comment: @HBP +1 You're right... I didn't think about that. I'll fix it.

Comment: @HBP But as other answers here, it's still happy with 02/31/2012. So I recommend to use a library like Datejs (or another but I use Datejs without problem).

Answer (score 0):

This one should do it:

```
((?:[0]?[1-9]|[1][012])[-:\\/.](?:(?:[0-2]?\\d{1})|(?:[3][01]{1}))[-:\\/.](?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d])
```

*(It is taken from txt2re.com)*

You should also take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

```
"/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/"
```

link:  [Javascript date regex DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateStr = '01/01/1901',
    dateObj = null,
    dateReg = /^(?:0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])\/(?:[012][1-9]|3[01]|[1-9])\/(?:19|20)\d\d$/;
    //             01 to 12 or 1 to 9   /    01 to 31  or  1 to 9   /  1900 to 2099

if( dateStr.match( dateReg ) ){
    dateObj = new Date( dateStr ); // this will be in the local timezone
}
```