# Grails date validation

Tags: validation, date, grails, groovy, gsp

I am new to Grails/GSP and want to implement date validation in Grails. Validation should be for input text in text field as required format is mm/dd/yyyy. Any guidance is appreciated. Also please point me to some good Grails and GSP tutorials if any one knows. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To require a specific date format for date input, you can use a custom property editor.

In `src/groovy/` you can add a class to register the custom editor which will be used in data binding.

```
class CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {
    void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
        def format = 'MM/dd/yyyy'
        def dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format)
        dateFormat.setLenient(false)
        registry.registerCustomEditor(Date, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true, format.size()))
    }
}
```

and register the bean in `resources.groovy`

```
beans = {
    customPropertyEditorRegistrar(CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar)
}
```

Comment: It is possible to validate based on multiple date formats? Let's say I want to allow `MM-dd-yyyy` and `yyyy-MM-dd`, can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Grails has a default date and time picker that it uses in scaffolds, you can use that but if you want a textbox to enter the date, you can validate the format using jQuery or javascript, then parse the string into date using:

```
try{
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
    date = format.parse(stringDate);
}catch (Exception e) {
    //something
}
```

You can use regular expression with javascript to validate the format of entered date in view. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy) might be useful for that.