# html & js text field data (DD-MM-YYYY) validation

Tags: javascript, html

In my form I have a text field in which user type date. Good habit tells me to not let user to put anything other then dgit and '-' symbol in the field.
 However i have a bit problem with implementing such feature. So far I Have a field which accept only digits. If user try to put in field letter, this letter is being removed. But the point is to create `(DD-MM-YYYY)`format so field have to accept '-' symbol.
 Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" name="test3" placeholder='DD-MM-YYYY' onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')"/>
```

i tried put `|\-` into regex but with no success. Can anyone point me where I am doing mistake?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, many have done this before,  google.

Comment: I just want to do this this way instead of using separate functions..

Comment: Use the regex `/[^\d-]/g` [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/puLtX/)

Comment: Also look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use thie regex

/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$|[^\d-]|-\d{2}-\d*-/

you can also

```
 **/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$|[^\d-]|-\d{2}-\d*-/.test(input.value)**
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
<input type="text" name="test3" placeholder='DD-MM-YYYY' onkeyup="if (/[^\d-]/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d-]/g,'')" onchange="validate(this)"/>

function validate(el){
    var regex = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-\d{4}$/;
    if(!regex.test(el.value)){
        alert('invalid date');
        el.value = '';
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/puLtX/1/)

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 has another approach for you:

```
<input type="date" name="test3">
```

The browser is responsible for the formatting of the date presentation, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with HTML5

see my jsfidle: http://jsfiddle.net/H7tMZ/2/

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="date" pattern="\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}" placeholder="dd-mm-jjjj"/>
    <button type="submit"/>
</form>
```