# Date format Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I have this regex to check date entry:

```
/^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$|^$/
```

I also need it to make sure that the format MM-DD-YYYY is followed.
I've tried these and they don't work.

```
/^[01-12]-[01-31]-[0-9]{4}$|^$/
/^['01'-'12']-['01'-'31']-[0-9]{4}$|^$/
```

How can I make this also check to make sure the MM part is 01-12 and the DD part is only
01-31?

Comment: try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: It does not seem like you are really after date check. 30th of Februari would be valid for example.

Comment: @Zim84, I modified the one there an it worked, please post as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @Juhana, not duplicate, the one on link that Zim84 posted worked great. Oh, BTW, thanks for the downvote by referring to the other post.

Comment: @ahdaniels, not really concerned about 30 of Feb.

Comment: ok, made a post. thx :)

Comment: It's pretty hard to believe the duplicate would not work if the other did. I also can't see how the downvote is my fault.

Comment: Not duplicate answers, that's for sure. Look at the one Zim84 provided, it is the one that led me to the solution. When you flag as duplicate it automatically gives a downvote.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Flagging for spam gives a downvote, other flags don't. (And I didn't even flag but voted to close.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regex that could help you:
[Javascript date regex DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy)

Please consider converting the string-to-validate into a date-object and see if its valid. This will actually validate it and will not accept dates like 31-02-9999

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
/^[0-1]{1}[1-2]{1}-[0-3]{1}[1-2]{1}-[0-9]{4}$|^$/
```

Comment: I think it invalidates anything starting with 10 or has 30 in the date(day) and validates date of 32. Should it not be /^[0-1]{1}[0-2]{1}-[0-3]{1}[01]{1}-[0-9]{4}$|^$/ It'll still say 31st of Feb is valid or 00 of 00 but it's close.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of crazy going with pure regex, i would go with regex + condition check as follows:

1. check with regex **/^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{4}$/**
2. // assuming myDate is ur string

   var dateParts = myDate.split('-');
   var bDateIsValid = ( Number( dateParts[0] ) <= 12 && Number( dateParts[0] ) >=1 ) && ( Number( dateParts[1] ) <= 31 && Number( dateParts[1] ) >=1 )

You may add also date if you wish