# Thymeleaf Error for <input> date with th:pattern

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use `th:pattern` for date input form field like following for a *thymeleaf* template using *spring-mvc* but without luck. Anybody else experienced similar thing and has some insight or alternative?

**I tried 1**. hard-coding the pattern

`<input type="text" th:pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" th:field="*{classDate}"/>`

received Error:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "MM/dd/yyyy"
```

**And 2**. setting pattern in java code for template to use

`<input type="date" th:pattern="${classdate_format}" th:field="*{classDate}"/>`

received Error:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring3.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor'
```

Answer (score 2):

`pattern` is *html5* attribute of `input` tag.

`pattern` validates an `input` value using *[regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*. So that value, which you inserts into `pattern` attribute should be correct *regex* pattern.

If you are using *Thymeleaf*'s `th:` prefix, template processor trying to find appropriate variable in *Spiring*'s model and insert it as a value of attribute. Thymeleaf is using *[Spring EL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)* for it's templates.

So your first approach is incorrect because of using invalid SpringEL expression.

The second solution looks better, `type="date"` gives you exactly what you want, but works [not for all browsers](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime). `${classdate_format}` looks like correct expression. To understand what causes the second error more code needed.

Anyway is there any reason to use `th:` prefix for `pattern` attribute? It needed only if you want to create regex pattern dynamically at server side. But in this case regex pattern is pretty straightforward, so you can use attribute without `th:`. To write correct regex for your case please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5465426/1430055).