# Match beginning of regex

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime

I'm writing a javascript program and I need to find the best way to match string against the *beginning* of regex. My exact problem is to validate starting symbols of date in `dd.mm.yyyy` format. For example, `31.1` and `31.12.201` would be valid but `31..` or `31.122` would not.

I do not need regex specifically - if there is an easier way to do this in javascript, fine.

EDIT. Note, that i'm looking for a match of *uncomplete* date which is not what's been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript date regex DD/MM/YYYY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```js
function validate(ele) {
  ele.style.color = /^(\d|\d{2}(\.\d?|(\.\d{2}(\.|\.\d{1,4})?)?))$$/.test(ele.value) ? 'green' : 'red';
}
```

```html
<input type=text id=date oninput="validate(this)">
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/bP8aS2/3)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: i got you. looks like lots of parenthesis shall be the only way with regexp. ugly, still.

Comment: @PedroLobito actually, there is no way to assure right date by starting fragment, for you don't know if `31.` will continue with `02` or not. Here it's enough to check for digits and dots.

Comment: @МаксимКоваль I disagree, you can efficiently validate a date in java script.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want:

```
mystring.match('^' + teststring) !== null
```

Where `mystring` would be `31.12.201` and `teststring` would be `31.1`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to match string as well :

```
function validStr(str)
{
    if(str.length > 10 ) //if length is more than valid char its invalid
        return false;
    var patt=/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3}/g; //use regex to match pattern like 31.12.201 digit twice.digit twice.and digit  3 or 4 times at last
    return patt.test(str);
}
alert(validStr("31.12.201"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate a date in the format of `dd.mm.yyyy` with `javascript` you can use:

```
re = /(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19|20\d{2})/;
```

**valid** `11/11/2015`
**invalid** `13/13/2015`

You can also use `Jquery` `datePicker` and validate with a regex, i.e.:

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker(
{
    onSelect: function()
    { 
        //var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
      
      var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
      console.log(date);
      
      if (/(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19|20\d{2})/.test(date)) {
 alert(date+" VALID DATE !")
} else {
 alert(date+" INVALID DATE !")
}

      
    }
});

//if the user tries to edit the field manually we check for any changes 

  $( "#datepicker" ).change(function() {
  var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
      console.log(date);
      
      if (/(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19|20\d{2})/.test(date)) {
 alert(date+" VALID DATE !")
} else {
 alert(date+" INVALID DATE !")
}
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```