# Find dates in text

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, text-mining

I want to find Dates in a document.

And return this Dates in an array.

**Lets suppose I have this text:**

```
On the 03/09/2015 I am swiming in a pool, that was build on the 27-03-1994
```

Now my code should return `['03/09/2015','27-03-1994']` or simply two Date objects in an array.

My idea was to solve this problem with regex, but the method `search()` only returns one result and with `test()` I only can test a string!

**How would you try to solve it?** Espacially when you dont know the exact format of the Date? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: In regard to converting to a Date object, how do you know if 01/09/2015 is 3 September or 9 March?

Comment: It is very easy to do with https://github.com/wanasit/chrono lib. It parses dates from input text in lots of possible formats!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** with regex **[`/\d{2}([\/.-])\d{2}\1\d{4}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/vJ7sH0/3)**

```js
var str = 'On the 03/09/2015 I am swiming in a pool, that was build on the 27-03-1994';

var res = str.match(/\d{2}([\/.-])\d{2}\1\d{4}/g);

document.getElementById('out').value = res;
```

```html
<input id="out">
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Or you can do something like this with help of capturing group

```js
var str = 'On the 03/09/2015 I am swiming in a pool, that was build on the 27-03-1994';

var res = str.match(/\d{2}(\D)\d{2}\1\d{4}/g);

document.getElementById('out').value = res;
```

```html
<input id="out">
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: `/\d{2}\[\/-\]\d{2}\[\/-\]\d{4}/g` notice -\ in class, that will invalidate the regex

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how would I have to change the regex to also get Dates that are written like `03.05.15` or `3.02.2014`

Comment: @JohnSmith By adding `.` in the class

Comment: Something like `/\d{1,2}\D\d{1,2}\D(\d{2}|\d{4})/g` seems more suitable, but what about dates like *3 September, 2015*?

Comment: I´am from Spain this Dates practically do not exist!

Comment: @RobG I really like your regex, can there be any char between the numbers? That would be great!

Comment: @RobG please write an answer so that I can rate it as correct!

Comment: @JohnSmith—`\D` matches any non–digit. maybe too broad, you could use `[-.\/]` instead.

Comment: Another thing, `.` don't need to be escaped when used in class

Comment: @RobG I used your regex but when I try it with `03.07.1994` for example it retruns `03.07.19`. It returns `19` instead of `1994` What do I have to change?

Comment: @JohnSmith : may be you are using `\d{2}` instead of `\d{4}`... can you create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @PranavCBalan I want `1994` as  well as `94` https://jsfiddle.net/8sdj4bpn/

Comment: @JohnSmith https://jsfiddle.net/8sdj4bpn/1/

Comment: @JohnSmith—swap the 2 and 4: `/\d{1,2}\D\d{1,2}\D(\d{4}|\d{2})/g`.