# How to query to couchdb by key and string search

Tags: database, nosql, couchdb

I'm new to CouchDB and I have documents like this:

```
{
    "credit_type" : "ADJ",
    "particular" : "Adjusted hours on 2018-01-01"
}
```

Then I have a view with this Map function

```
function(doc) {
   if(doc.credit_type == "ADJ") { emit(doc.particular, doc); }  
}
```

My view url is like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com:5984/_utils/database.html?client_docs/_design/adj/_view/adj
```

What I want to do is be able to query documents that will match my search key. The lookup field is the `particular` field.

The search key is a date like `2018-01-01` When I put they search url like

```
http://black-widow.remotestaff.com:5984/client_docs/_design/adj/_view/adj?key=20180-01-01
```

I should be able to fetch records which contains `2018-01-01` string in the `particular` field

I don't have any reduce function yet

Comment: I do not think your view is any help to you as it is not indexed on the information you want to find. You have two main options: go through all your "ADJ" docs and check the text of the "particular" field, or extract the date from the particular field and create a view to index it.

Comment: If you want to stick to text search, you will need Apache Lucene

Answer (score 0):

In order to search by some key, you must emit that key.

For you to be able to do this, I would suggest potentially moving the date out of the `particular` field, into its own field, this way you wont have to do any string parsing on the `particular` field to grab your date.

If you do not or can not do this, the you will have to parse the particular field for the date. This can be achieved by [this question and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949649/find-dates-in-text)*

Once you have gotten the date, you will need to emit it, so let me give you an example.

```
function(doc){
    String date = doc.particular.parse.date.here();

    emit([date, doc.credit_type], doc.particular);
}
```

Here, we parse the date from the `doc.particular` field, and emit it along with the credit type. Now, you can keep your `if` statement as it is, but doing it this way means you can search for ANY `credit_type`vs just the `ADJ`.

Now your keys should be `2018-01-01` and `ADJ`.

*You will need to make sure that CouchDB version of JS supports these functions.