# Regular expression on date in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, I'm trying to parse a string provided, in the form "DD/MM/YYYY"; the string can have one or two digits for day and month; for example:
8/10/2019 or 08/10/2019; 10/8/2019 or 10/08/2019.
I'have tried the following code, but ddDate is always null.

```
const regExp = new RegExp("^d{1,2}/d{1,2}/d{4}$");
const ddDate = dd.match(regExp)!;
```

Comment: And you haven't found a possible solution here on SO?

Comment: I've searched on SO, and I think my solution is right; however it does not work, so I asked because clearly there is something I don't know about regular expression and / or match function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript date regex DD/MM/YYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465375/javascript-date-regex-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote:

`^d{1,2}/d{1,2}/d{4}$`

- `/` needs to be escaped with `\`, i.e. `\/`
- `d` is going to match the string literal `d`. You *probably* wanted `\d` to match any number.

So, what you actually want:

`^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$`

```js
const regExp = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/; // or new RegExp("^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$");

console.log("12/12/2019".match(regExp)); // yes
console.log("2019/12/12".match(regExp)); // no
console.log("12/2019/12".match(regExp)); // no
```

I recommend testing this sort of thing at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FmBNBY/1)